# Macbook pro 2013 disable trackpad input completely

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, trackpad, kernel-extensions

I want to completely disable my trackpad, from startup if possible.

The trackpad on my 2013 macbook pro is not working properly anymore. Click/Tap does not register and neither alternate click. I believe the trackpad is in a "always clicking" state because hovering over elements that usually change their color is not triggered either.

Connecting a mouse, even with “**Ignore built-in trackpad when mouse or wireless trackpad is present**” option enabled, is not working either, the mouse click does not register, only right click works.

Only way I managed to make my mouse work properly was disabling some kexts ( I dont remember which ) and then restarting the computer with the mouse plugged in already. However, after removing the mouse and plugging it back again, it stopped working.

I don't have any possibility to go to a service due to the current situation, so I am looking for any temporary workaround that will allow me to use a mouse.

Answer (score 0):

The track pad is a USB device so the only way to disconnect it is to physically disconnect it.  However, you may have to disconnect the entire top case rendering your keyboard disconnected as well.

If you're having issues with the track pad, your best option is to replace it.  Disabling it by deleting kexts only lasts until the subsequent update.  With Catalina, you'll need to disable security (SIP) to delete the kexts which is counterproductive.

- [MacBook Pro Trackpad Suddenly Stopped Working Completely](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/235365/macbook-pro-trackpad-suddenly-stopped-working-completely/235514#235514)
- [2015 13" MacBook Pro Trackpad and Keyboard stop working](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/235692/2015-13-macbook-pro-trackpad-and-keyboard-stop-working/246403#246403)
- [Trackpad and keyboard of MacBook Pro unresponsive](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/195027/trackpad-and-keyboard-of-macbook-pro-unresponsive/195114#195114)

Comment: Due to the current situation I can neither replace it or physically disconnect it as no service is opened in my area. What kext should I delete/unload to only disable the trackpad?

Comment: Open the back cover, disconnect the top case from the logic board, replace the back cover, then use an external mouse and keyboard.  IFixit.com will have instructions on how to do this for your MacBook

Comment: If all, you want is the kext, it’s a dupe as it’s been asked/answered several times already.

Comment: The answer to the question that you linked is not relevant. I don't have that particular kext

Comment: Do not disconnect your trackpad from macbook as it will throttle the fan. The trackpad also hosts a therman sensor.